# When running SLI/Crossfire setups, would each device require their own swap chain?

Tags: directx, directx-12

I'm a total noob when it comes to coding with Graphics APIs. Currently, I'm coding using DX12 out of interest. While I'm not looking to support multi-GPU setups for my mini project, for future reference, I would like to know if each GPU would require it's own swapchain despite only one of them is connected to an output

Comment: multi-GPU is multiple GPUs rendering to a single display. Multi-monitor is one or more GPUs driving multiple displays. If you want to do the first, you need one swapchain.